# Fork RepositoryClarification

Tags: git, github

What will happen if two persons send the two Pull request for the same file(File.ksh) after Forking the repository?
Is there any problem will be there for merging?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what the users were changing. Git does diff calculation line by line, so if their changes are unrelated then there may be no problem. For example, if File.ksh contains a function to read text files and another function to count files in a directory, then Sally could make a PR that modifies the first function and Bob could make a PR that modifies the second function, and in theory there should be no conflict. You could merge these PR's in any order, and git will understand the modifications relate to different parts of the file.

However, if Sally and Bob were modifying the same code independently, then after merging one of their PR's the other one would run into merge conflicts.

tl;dr it depends on what changes were made in the Pull Requests and whether those changes are in conflict with each other.